# Slutsky's theorem, why converge in probability if already converging to a number c?

Tags: probability-theory

Slutsky's theorem states (among other things)

If $X_n$ converges in distribution to a random element $X$ and $Y_n$ converges in probability to a constant c, then

$X_n + Y_n$   →    X + c ; (where the arrow means converges in distribution)

The theorem imposes 2 conditions,

- that the convergence of Y is in probability,
- that is is to a number

But I cannot find an example of convergence in distribution to a number that is not also 
a convergence in probability to that same number

It seems to me that if $Y_n$ converges to the step function of c in distribution, then $Y_n$ converges to c in probability: as $Y_n$ converges in distribution, it has a CDF that converges to the step function, and this implies that, if I take epsilon around c, I will eventually find a distribution that has 99% percent probability inside the epsilon window.

Comment: This is correct and it is also well known. Convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability,

Comment: see theorem 5.5.13 in Casella Berger: The sequence of rv's $(X_1, X_2...)$ converges in probability to a constant $\mu$ if and only if the sequence converges also in Distribution to $\mu$

Comment: then why do the usual formulations of slutskys theorem include the hypothesis "converges to a constant in probability"?